# Low Quality Post (LQP): False positive audit?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I just encountered (and failed) [an audit in the Low Quality Post (LQP) review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26078979) that I *believe* to be a false positive—or, at minimum, a very nuanced example that probably isn't very effective for training purposes.

The post suggests using a Java library, then provides sample code of how to solve the problem using that library. I can't speak to whether the library is any good or if the code actually solves the original problem. But under most conditions I'd expect this to be an acceptable answer.

My assumption here is that the user had an undisclosed affiliation with the library and that the post was deleted as spam. If so, I wouldn't expect most reviewers to pick up on that, and especially without being able to click through on the user's profile to view a pattern of behavior.

Obviously, if I'm misunderstanding the audit, do let me know so I can update my rubric. But, generally, if I see an answer of the format, "Here's a solution using [a library](https://www.github.com)…" followed by a code sample, I've been clicking <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, yeah... We regularly deal with epidemics of BurningWave Core spam on Stack Overflow, and we moderators pretty much nuke it on sight. There is, unfortunately, almost no way for you as a regular user to know that, nor should you be expected to know it.

This is one of the problems with automatically-selected audits. They are not, as you said, "very effective for training purposes". This is why I (and several of the other moderators) are staunch advocates of revamping the audit system to allow us to nominate posts as audit candidates (both false-positives and false-negatives). We would select posts that are obvious and unmistakable, yet still represent corner-cases that often seem to trip up reviewers. This would be far more effective for pedagogical purposes, and I believe it would still scale adequately, as we could serve similar audits to all users without defeating the purpose.

Fortunately, failing a single audit will not cause you to be suspended from reviewing. This one didn't result in your suspension.

Audits can often be passed with 100% certainty by just taking a bit more time to study the situation. For example, try and open up the post in a new window (using the "link" link). If it's been deleted by a moderator, then you won't be able to see it (unless you have 10k+ reputation, in which case, you would see it but also see that it has been deleted and why), so you'll know that you're looking at an audit. This would have worked here, too, without requiring you to be able to access moderator-only contextual information about the associated user account.

Your rubric is fine. Library recommendations are acceptable as answers, assuming that there is some actual information provided in the body of the answer itself explaining how/why the answer solves the problem. (A code snippet is often sufficient, but not necessary. A bare link is never acceptable.) It's also often good to do a quick sanity check and make sure that the library is actually *somewhat* relevant to the question that was asked. A JavaScript library posed as an answer to a C++ question is probably gonna be spam, for example, but either way needs to be flagged for deletion.

Comment: I really love the idea of moderators being able to curate a set of posts for use in audits. In fact, what I'd _really_ like to see is a training period where new reviewers are given a set of e.g. ten or twenty representative no-penalty examples that they have to go through before being dumped into the "live" reviews. (Alongside, of course, the random spot checks as happen now.) Obviously, reviewers should also read the FAQ, when available, but well-selected audits would complement that nicely while providing real-world relevance.

Comment: Also, that's a good suggestion about cross-referencing e.g. the library's platform. I always click through on links to verify that they actually point to a library, source code, documentation, or article, but I usually don't evaluate them much beyond that. At minimum, validating the platform is a simple heuristic for identifying blindly posted promotional content.

Comment: Mhmm. Just be careful with blindly clicking links, @Jeremy. Although rare, it's possible that some of them may lead to malware or just undesirable content. I tend to study the link *target* (using my browser status bar) before clicking it. Sometimes, I'll even do a web search using the keywords just to make sure the link is taking me to a page matching expectations.

Comment: Aside, should I report cases like this in the future? Or, given that they're automatically selected, is there not much you can do about them? E.g. do you at least have the ability to remove a post from future audits? Or, even if you do, does that tend to just lead to a game of whack-a-mole, and especially in cases like this where it sounds like there were a _lot_ of these coming through?

Comment: @Jeremy There isn't much we can do about the automatically-selected posts. If it was *incorrectly* flagged as spam, then please do bring it to our attention. Otherwise, it may not be worth it. I'm almost certain that an edit will bump it out of consideration as an audit, so I've done that here to prevent this from tripping up anyone else in the future as a review audit. But that doesn't scale especially well. Better to do what I suggested in the penultimate paragraph and just pass the audit in the first place. :-)

Comment: Funny enough, I _did_ notice that this was an audit. In fact, if anything, I think the audits are too _easy_ to spot because of e.g. changes to the byline. But I didn't click through on the link because it seemed obviously valid. (I usually only click through on the link if there are other answer to determine if there's plagiarization or virtually identical answers; otherwise it's not part of my routine.) Regardless, I'll certainly be more aware of this in the future—at least for audits that seem suspiciously obvious. Once bitten, twice shy!