# What was the "severe quality issues" in this LQP review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I recently failed this LQP review audit:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26119435

It's supposed to be "*abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful.*"

But it seems to genuinely answer the question (with considerable detail). It doesn't look spammy, as it's not promoting anything. There are URLs there but it's the same tests links [posted in the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61141292/2745495). And there doesn't seem to be anything offensive in it. I also tried searching for bits and pieces of the text and the code, to check if it was plagiarized from somewhere else, but I couldn't find any copy of it.

I also checked the user who answered, and they're account is still active. (Though the account is curiously at 1 rep, with accepted answers but with no suspended banner.)

Actually, I already originally thought it was an audit, because it's a Java Q&A pair, and I have review filters that don't include Java. So, I could have recommended deletion to pass the audit but it seems wrong to judge on the basis of "*I know it's an audit because the tags don't match my filters*".

What was wrong about it? What was the *severe quality issues* that it had to be deleted?

Here's a patched-up image of the audit:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238647/dont-use-spam-post-as-audits-in-the-low-quality-review-queue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is spam, and was nuked as such by a moderator. The post is blatant self-promotion of Ralph Torello's Java library (by a user account known to be associated with Ralph himself), without the proper disclosure. And what you cannot see—but the moderator who deleted this as spam could see—is that a very large number of such answers were posted to the site by this account (and several other accounts), all promoting this library.

While the message displayed in the review queues was trying to warn you that the post could be spam, it is somewhat [poorly worded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397367/revise-this-post-has-severe-quality-issues-message), implying that the problem(s) to look out for are that the post is offensive, repulsive, or abusive. That's not going to be the case—posts nuked as "rude or abusive" are *not* displayed in the review queues as audits. Only posts nuked as spam are displayed as audits, so the message should really be focusing on spam, instead of just throwing that word in there as an afterthought.

[Many users have recently been tripped up by non-obvious spam in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397317/low-quality-post-lqp-false-positive-audit). The same advice that I gave there applies to you here. In summary, failing a single audit will not cause you to be suspended from reviewing, and it is entirely possible for you to pass these audits with 100% certainty just by opening them up in a new tab to see if they've been deleted already.

I'm not quite sure what to make of this sudden wave of folks being tripped up by non-obvious spam in the review queues. I don't know if the algorithm for picking audits was tweaked in some way, or if we simply have more folks reviewing (and thus naturally more edge cases). I've long been an advocate of hand-curated audits, and I think that would solve this problem. The moderator who nuked this particular post as spam would not have nominated it for use in audits.

Comment: I guess I could have also just Skipped seeing that it's Java, but I just had an itch to scratch. I've been reviewing in the LQP for quite some time now, and this is the 1st time I've come across something like this. Plus, usually, "long" detailed posts are "Looks OK". Anyways, thanks for the explanation.