# Failed review audit using the "needs more focus" flag

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

While reviewing the "First posts" queue, I came across a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66854655/php-8-function-alias-compatibility-getdir) that was obviously well-written and of high quality (judging from the language, formatting, provided links and content) but, at least to me, it seemed like it was obviously asking two questions. These questions were of course related, but I still considered that it should be flagged as such, and used the "needs more focus flag". I failed the audit, as you 've probably guessed from the title.

Now, I know that I should have probably skipped the question, or maybe even "cheat" in a way and view it out of the review queue. Also, maybe a question such as this can be considered as "focused" even if it actually does contain two questions, but still; a reviewer could flag it as non-focused even if he is paying attention. Since evaluating the latter is the goal of the audit, should a question such as this be used by the review audits?

**Disclaimer:** I have no hard-feelings of course for the review-auto-audit, as it is an automated system that is not perfect. I'm asking the above to understand if this case was actually a flaw of the audit, or if there's a point of view or something else that I'm not seeing, which should make me act differently in the future, since this resulted in my review privileges getting suspended.

**Edit:** My question is different from the duplicate [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit) as I want to know in the first place if the audit was correct or not (for this kind of problem/flagging), and if therefore the review-ban I received was fair (which I don't know yet). Assuming that it isn't, the audit/question should/could be flagged as such (I get that from the suggested post but I STILL don't know if this is the case here 100%), and I still don't know what to do about the review privileges suspension(act/don't act). **TL;DR** I know that the audit system makes mistakes. I don't think that this signifies that all failed audit questions/cases are the same. After all, there's a `disputed-review-audits` tag.

Comment: The best suggestion I've seen so far is to have mods nominate audits instead of automatic selection best on something unreliable as upvotes, eg. see [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397318/11682469).

Comment: While I might not have flagged that question (as you said it is well-written and well-received), I don't think it is a good audit and that you shouldn't feel bad. It is too much of a border case. Audits should be there to make sure you are paying attention and when something is obviously bad (or good) you act on it. I mean, it has a header saying **Questions**, with an `s` in the end...

Comment: "if the audit was correct or not" - The audit was valid.  The question isn't the author's first question.  **One could argue the entire point of the audit was to see if you recognized that fact.**  There was also nothing wrong with the question.  One does not receive an automatic review ban after a single failed audit.  Had you opened up the question in another tab, the fact it was an audit, would have been apparent to you.

Comment: [1] As implied by 2 other commenters, there WAS in fact something wrong with the audit/question. [2] The "first questions" queue requires from me to see if there's something wrong with the question itself, not to predict if the questioner is a new user or not. I really find this argument invalid. [3] The fact that I have failed two more audits overall (both ~ 20 days ago) is irrelevant, if the audit that resulted in my question ban is a faulty one, the ban should be removed.

Comment: I'm in agreement with you here; *especially* since this was a case where you flagged when you were "supposed" to say "looks okay". Usually when people fail these audits, it's  the other way around. You *were* paying attention. If that's truly the goal of audits, as many continue to hold, **you succeeded in paying attention, and got penalized for it anyway**. To me, this sounds wrong, outright.

Comment: @zcoop98 - Except there was nothing wrong with the question, so why was the question flagged or a comment submitted, if the question was opened in another tab it would have been clear it was an audit.

Comment: @SecurityHound There are *literally multiple questions asked* in the post, in bullets, under a heading that reads "Questions" plural. If that doesn't fall under at least the remote possibility of a justified "needs more focus" flag to you, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @SecurityHound To be clear, I'm not saying it's not a good post; I just think the flag was fully justified, even if we both disagree with the post needing to be closed.